# In R, split a dataframe so subset dataframes contain last row of previous dataframe and first row of subsequent dataframe

Tags: r, dataframe, subset

There are many answers for how to split a dataframe, for example [How to split a data frame?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3302356/how-to-split-a-data-frame)

However, I'd like to split a dataframe so that the smaller dataframes contain the last row of the previous dataframe and the first row of the following dataframe.

Here's an example

```
n <- 1:9
group <- rep(c("a","b","c"), each = 3)
data.frame(n = n, group)

  n  group
1 1     a
2 2     a
3 3     a
4 4     b
5 5     b
6 6     b
7 7     c
8 8     c
9 9     c
```

I'd like the output to look like:

```
 d1 <- data.frame(n = 1:4, group = c(rep("a",3),"b"))
 d2 <- data.frame(n = 3:7, group = c("a",rep("b",3),"c"))
 d3 <- data.frame(n = 6:9, group = c("b",rep("c",3)))
 d <- list(d1, d2, d3)
 d

[[1]]
  n group
1 1     a
2 2     a
3 3     a
4 4     b

[[2]]
  n group
1 3     a
2 4     b
3 5     b
4 6     b
5 7     c

[[3]]
  n group
1 6     b
2 7     c
3 8     c
4 9     c
```

What is an efficient way to accomplish this task?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Suppose `DF` is the original data.frame, the one with columns `n` and `group`.  Let `n` be the number of rows in `DF`.  Now define a function `extract` which given a sequence of indexes `ix` enlarges it to include the one prior to the first and after the last and then returns those rows of `DF`.  Now that we have defined `extract`, split the vector 1, ..., n by group and apply `extract` to each component of the split.

```
n <- nrow(DF)
extract <- function(ix) DF[seq(max(1, min(ix) - 1), min(n, max(ix) + 1)), ]
lapply(split(seq_len(n), DF$group), extract)

$a
  n group
1 1     a
2 2     a
3 3     a
4 4     b

$b
  n group
3 3     a
4 4     b
5 5     b
6 6     b
7 7     c

$c
  n group
6 6     b
7 7     c
8 8     c
9 9     c
```

Comment: The named list is handy here, too.

Answer (score 4):

Or why not try good'ol `by`, which "[a]ppl[ies] a Function to a Data Frame Split by Factors [`INDICES`]".

```
by(data = df, INDICES = df$group, function(x){
   id <- c(min(x$n) - 1, x$n, max(x$n) + 1)
   na.omit(df[id, ])
   })


# df$group: a
#   n group
# 1 1     a
# 2 2     a
# 3 3     a
# 4 4     b
# -------------------------------------------------------------------------------- 
#   df$group: b
# n group
# 3 3     a
# 4 4     b
# 5 5     b
# 6 6     b
# 7 7     c
# -------------------------------------------------------------------------------- 
#   df$group: c
#   n group
# 6 6     b
# 7 7     c
# 8 8     c
# 9 9     c
```

---

Although the `print` method of `by` creates a 'fancy' output, the (default) result is a `list`, with elements named by the levels of the grouping variable (just try `str` and `names` on the resulting object).

Answer (score 3):

I was going to comment under @cdetermans answer but its too late now. 
You can generalize his approach using `data.table::shift` (or `dyplr::lag`) in order to find the group indices and then run a simple `lapply` on the ranges, something like

```
library(data.table) # v1.9.6+ 
indx <- setDT(df)[, which(group != shift(group, fill = TRUE))]
lapply(Map(`:`, c(1L, indx - 1L), c(indx, nrow(df))), function(x) df[x,])
# [[1]]
#    n group
# 1: 1     a
# 2: 2     a
# 3: 3     a
# 4: 4     b
# 
# [[2]]
#    n group
# 1: 3     a
# 2: 4     b
# 3: 5     b
# 4: 6     b
# 5: 7     c
# 
# [[3]]
#    n group
# 1: 6     b
# 2: 7     c
# 3: 8     c
# 4: 9     c
```

Answer (score 1):

Could be done with data.frame as well, but is there ever a reason not to use `data.table`? Also this has the option to be executed with parallelism.

```
library(data.table)
n <- 1:9
group <- rep(c("a","b","c"), each = 3)
df <- data.table(n = n, group)
df[, `:=` (group = factor(df$group))]
df[, `:=` (group_i = seq_len(.N), group_N = .N), by = "group"]

library(doParallel)
groups <- unique(df$group)
foreach(i = seq(groups)) %do% {
  df[group == groups[i] | (as.integer(group) == i + 1 & group_i == 1) | (as.integer(group) == i - 1 & group_i == group_N), c("n", "group"), with = FALSE]  
}
[[1]]
   n group
1: 1     a
2: 2     a
3: 3     a
4: 4     b
[[2]]
   n group
1: 3     a
2: 4     b
3: 5     b
4: 6     b
5: 7     c
[[3]]
   n group
1: 6     b
2: 7     c
3: 8     c
4: 9     c
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is another dplyr way:

```
library(dplyr)

data = 
  data_frame(n = n, group) %>%
  group_by(group)

firsts = 
  data %>%
  slice(1) %>%
  ungroup %>%
  mutate(new_group = lag(group)) %>%
  slice(-1)

lasts = 
  data %>%
  slice(n()) %>%
  ungroup %>%
  mutate(new_group = lead(group)) %>%
  slice(-n())

bind_rows(firsts, data, lasts) %>%
  mutate(final_group = 
           ifelse(is.na(new_group),
                  group,
                  new_group) ) %>%
  arrange(final_group, n) %>%
  group_by(final_group)
```

Comment: Thanks for the dplyr way.  It improves on the similar method I used to solve the question that inspired this one: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33787624/in-r-is-it-possible-to-include-the-same-row-in-multiple-groups-or-is-there-oth.  Also have you seen 'lead' and 'lag'? https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/dplyr/vignettes/window-functions.html

Comment: Yeah, I always forget which packages have lag and lead. I've added them in above.